# How to play the music continously which are stored in NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, avaudioplayer

In tableview footer i have a play button to play the music, as the music starts tableview scrolls automatically according to the audio played but if the user tap on particular cell, the content in the particular cell is playing and stops but i want to continue the music from where the use taps to the end. Below is the code. Please help.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

int ref =(int) indexPath.row;


NSString *filePath = [soundArray objectAtIndex:ref];

NSString  *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *musicFile  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path];
myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:musicFile error:nil];


if (playing == YES) {
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause_White.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 [myAudioPlayer play];

         // playing = NO;

}


if (playing == NO) {
   // [playButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play_white.png"]       forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
}
```

SoundArray contains trimmed music. How to continue the song ? Help much appreciated.

Comment: I did not try in my xcode. But I think you can do it by below mentioned way. Take another object of AVAudioPlayer to play the content of each cell's music and when the cell's content starts to play, pause the main music. And when music corresponding to cell completed, play the main music. Hence forth you need to take two object of AVAudioPlayer, where one will be responsible to play main music and other will be for music corresponding to cell. Did you get my point?

Comment: Yes,i got it. Let me try and let you know.

Comment: Make a playlist for AVAudioPlayer

Comment: Playlist ? Will that works if songs are stored in NSArray ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code as per my concept. You may have to manage it more as its just a sample

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    isMainMusic = NO;

    // Construct URL to sound file
    NSString *path  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/1.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    mainMusicUrl    = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSString *path1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/2.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    secondMusicUrl  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];
}

-(void)playSecondaryMusic
{
    if ([playMainMusic isPlaying]) {
        [playMainMusic pause];
    }

    if (playSecondaryMusic) {
        playSecondaryMusic.delegate = nil;
        playSecondaryMusic = nil;
    }

    isMainMusic = NO;
    playSecondaryMusic  = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:secondMusicUrl error:nil];
    playSecondaryMusic.delegate = self;
    [playSecondaryMusic play];
}

- (IBAction)playMainMusic:(UIButton *)sender {

    if (playMainMusic) {
        playMainMusic.delegate = nil;
        playMainMusic = nil;
    }

    isMainMusic = YES;

    playMainMusic       = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:mainMusicUrl error:nil];
    playMainMusic.delegate = self;
    [playMainMusic play];

}
//Delegate method
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{

    if (isMainMusic)
    {
        NSLog(@"Main music");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Second music");
        [playMainMusic play];
        isMainMusic = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: where you are resuming the main  music after secondary music stops ??/

Comment: In the delegate method of AVAudioPlayer. I am editing my answer. have a look at it

Comment: What is not working? I have checked and the music plays and pause as per your requirement. But yes, i have taken one main music and one second music. When clicking button, I am playing main music and when i am clicking tableCell I pause the main music and start the second music. When second music completed, it will come to its delegate method "audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying" and there I am checking its for second music or not by the boolean value. It works. Can you tell me where it is not working??

Comment: Yes, It'w working fine by the way you said, but my requirement is when user tap on the on the tableviewcell, the music should continue from there, i don't want to start the main music again. Anyway upvote for this.Did you get my point ? Can you help with that ? Trimmed songs are in array and when user clicks on the cell it should continue from that place.

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. You have one main music and number of secondary music (as many as your table cell). You want to play your main music  when you click on the footer view's play button. right? Then when you click on a tableCell the main musicc should pause and the song corresponding to that tableCell will start. Am I right? Then when the music corresponding to tableCell stops, what wil happen? Please come with step by step.

Comment: Yeah right when the corresponding table cell stops, it should playing the next cell music not the main music.Got it ?Like a sequence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67199/discussion-between-janmenjaya-and-mac-play).